# QtQuick Rectangle control what borders show?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

How to draw a Rectangle and control if it is to show left or right borders or both using QtQuick 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `border` property in the `Rectangle` that allows you to add a border to your element. The issue is that you can't show only the left or the right border with it. To do that you have to add extra elements in your Rectangle to represent a border.

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 200
    color: "blue"

    Rectangle {
        id: borderLeft
        width: 1
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        color: "red"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: borderRight
        width: 1
        height: parent.height
        anchors.right: parent.right
        color: "red"
    }
}
```